# Get all elements details from android RecyclerView

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am working on Android application automation, in that I am facing issue with the recycler view data handling.

1. All data are appearing into Recycler view in List Format.
2. I have stored all items in **List** but at a time I am able to get only presented items on UI.

I need all items into List??

[image: Need to access those MobileElement on Screen]

Comment: Please share corresponding xml for RecyclerView and child nodes too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add initial data into your `List`, then perform some action to show another data (scroll, refresh or whatever, it based on application logic) and append these data to your list. Keep doing it until you collect all data. What is the actual issue you faced with?

Comment: I have tried to get data with scroll but when I scroll memory allocation for upper 6 items (6 items present at once on-screen) are shifted to the next 6 items.
That's why when I try to access the previous 6 items. 
Code will throw an error - No such element found

Comment: Why you trying to get access to the previous items? just dynamically collect them into `List`, thats all. You can achieve that with, for example, `stream` `distinct`